# How to get select area coordinate with python?

Tags: python, screen, area

I would like to know if there is a simple way to get coordinates of an area selected with the mouse on screen?

Imagine, I have a small gui, clicking a "select" button then I draw a select area on my screen and it returns the top-left / bottom-right coordinate of my selected area.

And also which kind of gui should I use to be multi platform compatible? 
wxPython / wkTinker, any other?

Thanks to point me on the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The first question depends on the second, but usually you have something like a mousePressed and a mouseRelease event which both provide coordinates (see [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) for Tkinter). A selected rectangle is defined by the coordinates of those two events.

The second question is rather subjective and also depends on what you want to do exactly. But another option would be [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro).